# Replace data at specific character, then change value after x lines

Tags: awk, sed, scripting

I have a text file, all the values of the 23rd character are `0` but I need them to be value `X` which starts at `1` and increments every `58` lines until it reaches a final value of `64`.

I tried using this `sed` code, but it's not specific and changes all `0` values to `64` values.

```
for i in $(seq 1 1 64); do
   sed -e "s/0/$i/g" file.txt > newfile.txt
done
```

What I have is;

```
ATOM  1     C0   ODA  0          1.452   2.430  23.632  1.00  1.00           C
ATOM  2     C1   ODA  0          1.839   1.672  22.372  1.00  1.00           C
...
ATOM  3711  H56  ODA  0         30.750  32.945   0.998  1.00  1.00           H
ATOM  3712  H57  ODA  0         31.934  32.195   0.165  1.00  1.00           H
```

And what I want is;

```
ATOM  1     C0   ODA  1          1.452   2.430  23.632  1.00  1.00           C
ATOM  2     C1   ODA  1          1.839   1.672  22.372  1.00  1.00           C
...
ATOM  3711  H56  ODA  64        30.750  32.945   0.998  1.00  1.00           H
ATOM  3712  H57  ODA  64        31.934  32.195   0.165  1.00  1.00           H
```

I'm not married to using `sed` it's just about the limit of my bash knowledge.  I think `awk` might be better but I don't know anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -lpe 's/^.{22}\K0/$. % 58 ? $a||0 : $a++/e'  yourfile
```

## Brief:

Skip the first 22 chars and keep them aside from appearing in the matching due the `\K` and the 23rd char for sure is a `0` per your spec. 
The line number `$. % 58` will tell us whether we need to keep the counter held or incremented.

Comment: The OP said "columns", not "characters".

Comment: The input and expected data given by the OP shows the change occurring in the 23rd char. position. I too had the same confusion, but then saw there were no more than 11 columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need to modify a specific character position in `awk`, then you can set an empty field field separator:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""; OFS=FS} {$23 = int(FNR / 58) + 1 ; print}' file
```

OTOH if you really want to modify the fifth whitespace-separated *field* then you can just use the default separator

```
awk '{$5 = int(FNR / 58) + 1 ; print}' file
```

Comment: There is something strange happening when I use these commands, the value of that is replaced changes on the 57th line each time.  I tried changing `58` to `59` but that just completely broke it.

Answer (score 0):

To replace only the 0 in the 23rd column (or in your given example the 5th column) you need something like this:

```
sed -e "s/^\(\(\S\S*\s\s*\)\{4\}\)0 /\1$i/" file.txt > newfile.txt
```

But this remark is just to improve your sed knowledge. Replacing with incrementing variables is no typical sed job. It's possible but not practical. You could mix sed with a shell script, but perhaps you better use the script language of your choice like python or perl.